# How to add a database field name and its value to a listbox with spacing in between in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox

**Beforehand: Creating the project in Windows Forms.**

In C# I am trying to create an application which lists some database values in a Listbox but I am looking for a better way to add 2 database values (field name and its value) to the listbox with spacing between them. I'll explain it a bit further below.

The values that I am displaying in the Lisbox are from an Access database and are a. the field names of a specific database table and b. the values of those fields.
The Listbox looks like this:

[image: image example]

The names in the left side of the listbox are the field names of the database table. These are inserted in the listbox on the load of the listbox. The right values are the matching values of those fields which are taken (with a reader) from the database.

Here is the code that lists these values and field names:

```
while (reader2.Read())
{

    listBox2.Items.Add("Boodschappen:" + "€ ".PadLeft(32) + reader2["Boodschappen"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Woonverzekering:" + "€ ".PadLeft(28) + reader2["Woonkosten"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Essent:" + "€ ".PadLeft(46) + reader2["Essent"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Ziggo:" + "€ ".PadLeft(48) + reader2["Ziggo"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Huur:" + "€ ".PadLeft(49) + reader2["Huur"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Zorgverzekering Wendy:" + "€ ".PadLeft(18) + reader2["Zorgverzekering Wendy"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Zorgverzekering Nicolas:" + "€ ".PadLeft(17) + reader2["Zorgverzekering Nicolas"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Autoverzekering:" + "€ ".PadLeft(31) + reader2["Autoverzekering"].ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("Benzine:" + "€ ".PadLeft(44) + reader2["Benzine"].ToString());                   
}
```

As you can see in the code, the database field names are added manually ("field name") to the listbox while the field name values are retrieved from the database. I also manually added the spacing (PadLeft) to outline the values correctly and added the € symbol.

So far so good.

The problem however is the following: the user should also be able to add a new field name to the database table manually with C# code (see in the picture the Voeg veld toe = Add field), BUT when someone adds a new field manually the field name can not be added to the listbox automatically like the other (default) ones since I don't know beforehand what field names are being added, how much spacing is needed, etc.

I thought about setting up two listbox next to each otter so I have a better controlling of spacing, naming and so on but this doesn't look very fancy (and I like the way you can select an entire row in the listbox).

So the question is: **How can/should I modify my code so it is easier to add custom database field names to my listbox and with good outlining (spacing)?**
And is it even possible to readout database field names with a reader together with its value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the fields names and values exist in the same table of your Access DB. If that is true, then all you have to do is change the select query where you fetching the values, in order to get the coresponding names. Example:

```
private void UpdateListBox()
{
   List<string> myList=new List<string();
   listBox2.DataSource=null; //Clear existing binding;
   string query="Select FieldName,FieldValue from Mytable";
    int x=100; //Max padding
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, Myconn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
                while (readerr.Read())
                {
                   myList.Add(reader[0].ToString()+":" + "€"PadLeft(x-reader[0].ToString().Length) + reader[1].ToString());      
                }
            }
listBox2.Datasource=myList; 
}
```

The above function will be called every time you update your table. (Input data on your form).
if the field name and value are on a differnet table you just need to use a join query to get them on the same select statement, e.g:

```
string query="Select FieldName.tableA,FieldValue.tableB from tableA join tableB on tableA.CommonField=tableB.CommonField";
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to make some modifications but works like a charm!